# What does name comparison mean on WPF/C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a textbox in my xaml --> `x:Name="textBoxId"`. In the code behind I have used a method `OnRoutedEvent(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)`.

I also have used the following:

`source == textBoxId`

How can I use name comparison instead of object comparison?

What does name comparison mean?

Comment: _"How can I use name comparison instead of object comparison?"_ -- why would you want to? The reference equality comparison you're using now is more efficient. Please explain your question better; provide a good [mcve] showing clearly what you're trying to do, explain precisely what that code does now, what you want it to do instead, and what _specifically_ you're having trouble figuring out.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I use name comparison instead of object comparison?

You need to cast the source to a `FrameworkElement`:

```
private void OnRoutedEvent(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    FrameworkElement fe = sender as FrameworkElement;
    if (fe != null && fe.Name == "textBoxId")
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

There is no real point in doing this though. You might as well compare the references:

```
private void OnRoutedEvent(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if(sender == textBoxId)
        ...
}
```

> What does name comparison mean?

I guess it means that you are comparing *the names* of two elements, rather than comparing the element references themselves.